# Why does my pc sleep when I want it to hibernate?

Tags: sleep, hibernate, thinkpad, windows-10-pro

This is my first question on stack exchange.

I have a three-day old thinkpad t590 running windows 10 pro. It has 1tb ssd and 24gb memory. My problem is I noticed that whenever I set my pc to hibernate, be it manually clicking the hibernate button or after a timer, I am pretty sure that it just goes to sleep. What I know is hibernate is like shutting down the pc, but it saves whatever apps you have open. But, this isn't the case as when I tell the pc to hibernate, the screen goes black and when I press a key or touch the touchpad, it wakes up showing the login screen immediately instead of the startup screen, which is what I am pretty sure sleep does. I don't know if this is relevant, but when I do shutdown /h in cmd as admin, it goes to sleep instead of hibernate because the cmd displays `element not found 1168`.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> I have a three-day old ThinkPad T590 running Windows 10 pro.

I have a ThinkPad X1 running Windows 10 Pro working well.

1. Do not hesitate to call Lenovo Support if you think something is not right. Their warranty support is top notch,
2. New = run Lenovo Driver Update (System Update) and update ALL drivers including BIOS.
3. Check Advanced Power Settings and be sure (at least for a week or so) that Hybrid Sleep is OFF, use Manual for Suspend, and let Hibernate be Automatic.

Consider only using Suspend. That machine will suspend overnight and not lose much charge at all. I do this. Try this for a week, turn Hybrid Sleep OFF and Hibernate OFF and get used to the machine.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time, but you won't believe how much time I wasted with lenovo support. Don't get me started how negative my experience was with them. After countless hours, they said software support wasn't included in my warranty, which is why I am here. Regarding system update, I believe I have updated everything in lenovo vantage and windows update. Third, for some reason I don't have any field for "Allow hybrid sleep". Probably this is what is causing the issue. Any further help is appreciated.

Comment: Hybrid sleep may vary by machine. I have a seven year old X230 here without it. Did you try disabling Hibernate as I suggested?   Suspend alone will do everything.

Comment: I am assuming suspend means sleep mode. I want to actually use the hibernate function, not disable it. I even disabled it and re-enabled it, but the problem still persists. Do you know how to fix my hibernation issue instead of disabling it?

Comment: If you disabled hibernate and used sleep (suspend) and there is still a problem, then escalate with Lenovo and perhaps ask to have the machine replaced. It is morning here and my two laptops here were suspended overnight and I just opened the lid to wake them up and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

windows i think now uses hybrid sleep so it basically is going into sleep and doing hibernate which is different then what your used to. it does it so the pc will wake faster and in the event of a power loss you will still be where you left off.

i was going to suggest you could pull the power cord and the battery to test but maybe you can't so easily disconnect your battery.

anyway why do you want it to hibernate instead of sleep? i disable hibernate myself so my ssd lasts longer.

i believe modern laptops use a lot less power in sleep mode than old ones so it shouldn't use as much battery as you might be used to.

Comment: really ssd lasts longer if hibernate mode isn't used? never knew. alright i guess I shouldn't care if hibernate works.